# Unix: sort by last number of line

Tags: unix

How do you sort a file by the last number in a line?

Assuming the last character of every line is a number.  INPUT:

```
facebook.com/pageA,2,11,11
facebook.com/pageB,0,0,20
facebook.com/pageC,0,0,6
facebook.com/pageD,1,22,239
```

Desired Output:

```
facebook.com/pageC,0,0,6
facebook.com/pageA,2,11,11
facebook.com/pageB,0,0,20
facebook.com/pageD,1,22,239
```

Help??

Comment: Assume the lines have same number of comma-separated columns. You can read `man sort` to find how to specify the separator and how to sort numerically.

Comment: Your example doesn't match your question.  Which do you want:  sort by last _digit_ or by last _number_?

Comment: last number.. but what is the difference between number and digit? they mean the same thing right?

Comment: @user1899415, not same thing. Digit is a element(character) of number.

Comment: ah I see.. sorry for the confusion, question edited.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `sort`.

```
sort -n -t, -k4 INPUT
```

Comment: assumed input has 4 columns.

Answer (score 3):

If your input file has different columns in each line then you can make the last column as first column, sort by it and then remove it.

```
awk '{print($NF,$0)}' FS=, OFS=, inputFile | sort -t, -nk1 | cut -f2- -d,
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me because I don't have a constant number of fields.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rev` to reverse each line, then sort, then re-reverse:

```
rev < $file | sort | rev
```

Comment: Sigh ... the OP's example doesn't match the question.  I answered the question, not the example.  Apparently the goal is to sort by the last _number_ on the line, not the last _digit_ on the line.  It's so hard to give people what they _want_ instead of what they ask for.

Comment: This does not produce OP's desired output because last number are reversed and compared. OP writed 'digit', but he want number actually.

Comment: Right.  Read my comment, just above yours.